# Can I run JAR file which includes another JAR file under lib folder in HDInsight?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to run a JAR file in HDInsight which includes another JAR file under the lib folder?

### JAR file

├/folder1/subfolder1/myApp/…
│　              　　└.class file 
|
| 
└ lib/dependency.jar   // library （jar file）

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On HDInsight, we should be able to run a Java MapReduce JAR, which has a dependency on another JAR. There are a few ways to do this, but typically not by copying the second JAR under lib folder on headnode.
Reasons are – Depending on where the dependency is, you may need to copy the JAR under the lib folder of all worker nodes and headnodes – becomes a tedious task. Also, this change will be erased when the node gets re-imaged by Azure, and hence not a supported way.

Now, there are two types of dependencies –
1.       MapReduce driver class has dependency on another external JAR 
2.       Map or reduce task has dependency on another JAR, where Map or Reduce functions calls an API on the external JAR.

Scenario #1 (MapReduce driver class depends on another JAR):
we can use one of the following options –

a.       Copy your dependency JAR to a local folder (like d:\test on windows HDI) on the headnode and then use RDP to append this path to HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable on head node– this is suitable for dev/test to run jobs directly from headnode, but won’t work with remote job submissions. So this is not suitable for production scenarios.

b.      Using a ‘fat or uber jar’ to include all the dependent jars inside your JAR – you can use Maven ‘Shade’ plugin , example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/11/04/how-to-use-hbase-java-api-with-hdinsight-hbase-cluster-part-1.aspx)

Scenario #2 ( Map or Reduce function calls API on external JAR) - 
Basically use –libjars option.

1. If you want to run the mapreduce JAR from Hadoop command line - 
   a.       Copy the Mapreduce JAR to a local path (like d:\test )
   b.       Copy the dependent JAR on WASB

Example of running a mapreduce JAR with dependency-

hadoop jar D:\Test\BlobCount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar css.ms.BlobCount.BlobCounter -libjars wasb://mycontainername@azimwasb.blob.core.windows.net/mrdata/jars/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar -DStorageAccount=%StorageAccount%  -DStorageKey=%StorageKey% -DContainer=%Container% /mcdpoc/mrinput /mcdpoc/mroutput

The example is using HDInsight windows – you can use similar approach on HDInsight Linux as well.

2. Using PowerShell or .Net SDK (remote job submission) –With PowerShell, you can use the –LibJars parameter to refer to dependent jars. 
   you can review the following documentations, these have various examples of using powerShell, SSH etc.
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-mapreduce/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-mapreduce/

I hope it helps!

Thanks,
Azim